# Github Pages renders blank page

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I just pushed a blank Jekyll site to my github pages. https://louissafety.github.io/ However, instead of rending the default jekyll page, it renders the blank page.  What could be wrong.

It works fine on the local machine.

Github page : https://github.com/louissafety

Comment: This seems fixed after GitHub Pages updated to Jekyll 3.3

Answer (score 1):

While your site is properly setup to use `jekyll`, it's using ruby gems that are not available to `github-pages`.

The only lines that you're supposed to have in your `Gemfile` are:

`source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'github-pages', group: :jekyll_plugins`

Any other gems or includes may not be available to Github Pages, causing the jeykll biuld to fail

Comment: I removed the Gemfile and pushed the files. But still gets the blank page.

Comment: now does it build locally? i'm guessing not, because you don't have `minima` installed. you need to pull `minima` into your repo and get that building locally first. you can use the `github-pages` gem to test

Answer (score 0):

If you try to use a custom theme for which the gem is not whitelisted by GitHub, you might need to declare the custom theme in your `_config.yml` file as `remote_theme: github_user/repo`, and remove it from your `Gemfile`.

Here is my `Gemfile`:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem 'github-pages', group: :jekyll_plugins
```

And the interesting part of my `_config.yml`:

```
remote_theme: pawamoy/jekyll-readthedocs
```

To build locally, just run `bundle exec jekyll serve`.

More information on the [GitHub help page for Jekyll themes](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-jekyll-theme-to-your-github-pages-site/).