# Github pages is showing my ReadMe file not the html file?

Tags: github, github-pages

Why is my github pages showing my readme file and not the index.html?

repo:
https://github.com/TomAk1993/To-do-list

githubpages:
https://tomak1993.github.io/To-do-list/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github Pages renders blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39945114/github-pages-renders-blank-page)

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing any index.html file in your github. If todolist.html is the one refering to, maybe try renaming it to index.html. That should work.

Comment: Thanks, I've just done this, do I need to do anything else, or will it just automatically work?

Comment: Yes that much should work. Incase it didn't by now, try making an empty commit to your github repo and push it.
`git commit --allow-empty -m "Empty commit"`