# HTML not pulling up on GitHub pages

Tags: github, github-pages-deploy-action

The published page only pulls up the ReadMe file. When I check the actions, the flow shows that it is picking up the HTML file, but it's not pulling it through to run it on the published page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github Pages renders blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39945114/github-pages-renders-blank-page)

Answer (score 0):

I made this question to let people know how I fixed this issue. I found a few other threads about a similar issue. Most peoples' resolved itself and would display the HTML file. I had tried multiple commits to push a redeploy, but this had no effect. I had to move the HTML file (I also went ahead and moved the CSS and Java file too) one folder layer out, which fixed the issue. So my HTML file was no longer nested in a folder within the overall folder. It's directly in the main file, displaying directly in the repo, and deploying correctly. Hope this helps somebody.